# How do I over-ride the save() method for my Django model so that it updates properly?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a ratemyprofessors type of application for my school and also to get some practice.

Currently my **models.py** looks like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

UNIVERSITIES = (
    .....
)

DEPARTMENTS = (
    .....
)

class Professor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name_code = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=UNIVERSITIES)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DEPARTMENTS)
    total_rating_points = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    number_of_reviews = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    rating = models.FloatField(
        validators = [MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(5.0)],
        default = 0.0
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

SCORE_CHOICES = (
    .....
)

class Review(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_reviews')
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor, related_name='professor_reviews')
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=SCORE_CHOICES)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('author', 'professor')]

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Professor: ' +self.professor.name +', Score: ' +str(self.rating)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Re-writing the save method to update the associated professor's
        rating as soon as a new Review object is created.
        Also accounts for review updates by the user.
        """
        if self.pk is None:
            # This means that this is a new object
            if self.professor:
                p = self.professor
                # Adjusting the total_rating_points and number of reviews
                p.total_rating_points += self.rating
                p.number_of_reviews += 1
                # Adjusting the rating
                p.rating = float(p.total_rating_points) / float(p.number_of_reviews)
                p.save()
        else:
            # This object already exists, so this is an update
            self.updated = timezone.now()
            **WHAT DO I DO NOW?**


        super(Review, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You see, if a user updates his/her rating, the rating of the professor has to be adjusted accordingly. Since this is the core of the application, I wanted to do it in the save() method. It works nicely if it is a very new review. However, how do I update the score?

I mean I know what I have to do:

- Subtract the previous score from the total_rating_point of the professor.
- Add the new rating to the total_rating_point
- Calculate rating by dividing it with number_of_review.

However, how exactly do I retrieve the previous score in the save() method during an update? Also is there a better and more efficient to do what I am trying to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple concerns to keep in mind: What if a user deletes their account, a review, etc? Keeping a running total in the way shown would be problematic.

Instead, I'd suggest a structure such as I've shown below; when a `Review` is updated, save it and then call the save method for `Professor`. The new save method for `Professor` runs calculates the sum and count of reviews in place, recalculating each time as it still is only reaching out to the DB for a couple queries.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class Professor(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if self.pk: # prevent hitting the database unless professor already exists
            professor_reviews = Review.objects.filter(professor=self)
            # Adjusting the total_rating_points and number of reviews
            self.total_rating_points = professor_reviews.aggregate(Sum('rating'))
            self.number_of_reviews = professor_reviews.count()
            # Adjusting the rating
            self.rating = float(self.total_rating_points) / float(self.number_of_reviews)
        super(Professor,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

class Review(models.Model):
    ....         
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk: #already exists
            self.updated = timezone.now()
        super(Review, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.professor.save() # call after super writes the Review to the DB
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a much better way to do things I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Use a post_save signal.

In the models file with the Professor:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save,sender=Review)
def update_professor_by_review(*args,**kwargs):

 updated_review = kwargs['instance']
 reviewed_professor = updated_review.professor
  # ... update the reviewed_professor as needed according to the review instance
  reviewed_professor.save()
  return
```